# How to programmatically change the selected item in this drop down menu?

Tags: javascript, jquery, vbscript, vb6

```
<DIV class="uiMenu uiSelectorMenu" role=menu>
<UL class=uiMenuInner bindPoint="menu">
<LI class="uiMenuItem uiMenuItemRadio uiSelectorOption  checked" data-label="Paused"><A aria-checked=true class=itemAnchor role=menuitemradio tabIndex=0 href="#" rel=ignore><SPAN class="itemLabel fsm"><SPAN class=icon_wrap><IMG class="selector icon" src="/images/adz/ad_states/paused.gif"></SPAN>Paused</SPAN></A></LI>
<LI class="uiMenuItem uiMenuItemRadio uiSelectorOption " data-label="Active"><A aria-checked=true class=itemAnchor role=menuitemradio tabIndex=1 href="#" rel=ignore><SPAN class="itemLabel fsm"><SPAN class=icon_wrap><IMG class="selector icon" src="/images/adz/ad_states/running.gif"></SPAN>Active</SPAN></A></LI>
<LI class="uiMenuItem uiMenuItemRadio uiSelectorOption " data-label="Deleted"><A aria-checked=true class=itemAnchor role=menuitemradio tabIndex=2 href="#" rel=ignore><SPAN class="itemLabel fsm"><SPAN class=icon_wrap><IMG class="selector icon" src="/images/adz/ad_states/deleted.gif"></SPAN>Deleted</SPAN></A></LI></UL></DIV></DIV><SPAN bindPoint="copy_link_wrapper"><A class=copy_link href="#"></A></SPAN></DIV><SELECT bindPoint="select"><OPTION value=""></OPTION><OPTION selected value=2>Paused</OPTION><OPTION value=1>Active</OPTION><OPTION value=99>Deleted</OPTION></SELECT> </DIV></TD>
<TD id=td_time_start_html_last_row class=td_time_start_html ?>
```

Above is the HTML code for the drop down menu I want to change.

At the end of the code it has SELECT, OPTION etc.. which I can normally change things on, but when I change the selectedIndex it doesn't do anything on the website, I am assuming the beginning part of the code has something to do with that.

Here is my VB6 code (note you can show me in any language)

```
For i = 0 To Form1.WebBrowser1.Document.All.length - 1 '
    If Form1.WebBrowser1.Document.All.Item(i).nodeName = "SELECT" Then
        For x = 0 To Form1.WebBrowser1.Document.All.Item(i).Options.length - 1
            If InStr(Form1.WebBrowser1.Document.All.Item(i).Options(x).Text, "Active") > 0 Then
                Form1.WebBrowser1.Document.All.Item(i).selectedIndex = x
            End If
        Next x
    End If
Next i
```

When I run that code, and I check the items value with
Debug.Print Form1.WebBrowser1.Document.All.Item(i).Options(x).Selected
it does return true and the previous selected does say false, but on the website the item doesn't change/update.

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: By any chance is you browser embedded in a VB6 WinForms app? Nothing is clear from the code :)

Comment: As you appear to be doing browser automation of external websites, might I suggest you use a library like WatiN or Selenium? Doing it at such a low-level with unstructured code is a recipe for long hours and poor results. You are currently searching the Entire DOM for one `SELECT` when you can do the same with a single line in most automation libraries.

Comment: HiTech, yea I am using the WebBrowser in VB6, I believe its an IE plugin (not sure tho).  Regarding your suggestion, the reason I had to do the loop way was because the select didnt have an ID.. but theres only 2 selects on the page, so its not a big deal... also this drop down menu change is the only thing I have to do :)

edit: ah I just realized what you meant.. ya its pretty inefficient I guess, but like I said I only need to do this 1 thing, so I dont mind

Answer (score 1):

Use the .selected property of the option; that will update the .selectedIndex of the select automagically. POC .HTA:

```
<html>
 <head>
  <Title>select</Title>
  <hta:application id="select" scroll = "no">
  <script type="text/vbscript">
   Function doIt()
     ' select Item2
     With document.getElementById("lbDemo")
       MsgBox "Before: " & .selectedIndex
       .options(1).selected = True
       MsgBox "After: " & .selectedIndex
     End With
   End Function
  </script>
 </head>
 <body>
  <select id="lbDemo" size="4">
   <option value=Item1>Item1</option>
   <option value=Item2>Item2</option>
   <option value=Item3>Item3</option>
  </select>
  <hr />
  <input type="button" value="select 2" onclick="doIt" />
 </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Hi, I previously tried Form1.WebBrowser1.Document.All.Item(i).Options(x).Selected=true
And it has the same results

I'm thinking that SELECT code is bogus/hidden and the site is using the code before that  "uiMenu uiSelectorMenu"  etc

Answer (score 1):

Not sure how much this will help, as I ran up the sample in a VisualBasic 2012 Win-Forms app,

```
Dim selectList = WebBrowser1.Document.GetElementsByTagName("select").Item(0)
selectList.SetAttribute("selectedIndex", 2)
```

but using your HTML snippet as the page content of a web-browser control, the above code correctly selected the second item in the drop-down list `"Active"` using only the HTMLElement class. Screen shot below:

[image]

If you can post the complete source code somewhere it may be easier to figure out your specific problems.

Comment: No luck :(.. like I said to a different poster, Im pretty sure the SELECT drop down menu in the html is just bogus and its using the stuff before that.  I can post the entire HTML.. its pretty big tho (anyway to attach a file?).. fyi its from a facebook page for their advertisements.  I am making a small app that pauses ad campaigns.

Comment: @user1088794: It is likely using JQuery to update options programmatically. There is no easy way to post files. Best to find a web-site to post the project. You can always contact me through my website link. Cheers.

Comment: Thanks HiTech, I appreciate the help.  I will contact you shortly :)